# Generalization of the Chinese remainder theorem

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-algebras

Let $A$ be a Banach algebra and $\{I_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha}$ be a collection of closed two-sided pairwise coprime ideals of $A$. Is the Chinese remainder theorem true for $A$ and $\{I_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha}$?

Comment: First, the CRT requires that the ideals be comaximal, not merely coprime; second, it doesn't apply if there are infinitely many ideals. Modulo that (that is, assuming finitely many pairwise comaximal ideals), the CRT is true for general rings, and thus also for Banach algebras.

Comment: @DavidHandelman What do you think about adding some conditions and concluding this theorem for infinitly many ideals?

Comment: Dear pseudonym, surely it is up to you to think of what conditions might lead to a good version of the CRT. You cannot expect to do research merely by taking known results and asking other people how to formulate generalizations. I would start by thinking of a Banach algebra where a lot is known about the closed ideals, or where there is a natural family of closed ideals you are interested in, and seeing if some weaker form of CRT holds there